# Code hook before EntityManager is initialized in JBoss AS 6

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, jakarta-ee

I'm looking for a **callback facility** that allows me to execute some code *before an EntityManager is started* in **JBoss 6**.

More specifically, I would like to process a Liquibase changelog, before the EntityManager is initialized.

Any hints greatly appreciated!
J.

Comment: You probably mean `EntityManagerFactory`, not `EntityManager`, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring or AspectJ?  It sounds like [writing an aspect is exactly what you want](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-defn):

7.2.4.1 Before advice

Before advice is declared in an aspect using the @Before annotation:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LiquibaseChangelogAspect {

  @Before("javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()")
  public void processChangelog() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

You might have to tweak the method name in the `@Before` annotation to exactly what you want because JBoss might be using proxies or whatever.

Comment: Interesting approach... However, I'm not using Spring, nor AspectJ.  Maybe JEE6 Interceptors can deliver the same functionality?

Comment: Yeah, looking at `javax.interceptor`, looks like interceptors would work too!  Good call.